# Вебсокеты. Ratchet пример. uncaught exception: protocol error (welcome message received more than once)

Tags: php, javascript, websocket, ratchet

Подключил библиотеки и скопировал\вставил код со страницы примера http://socketo.me/docs/push . Запускаю push-server.php, захожу на главную страницу проекта и получаю ошибку **uncaught exception: protocol error (welcome message received more than once)**.

Пару недель назад пробовал этот пример и он работал. Но после этого я переустановил Windows и WampServer.

Привожу структуру и код проекта.

```
newproject2\
 bin\
  push-server.php
 src\
  MyApp\
   Pusher.php
 vendor\ (react, guzzle и т.д.)
 composer.json
 composer.lock
 index.php
```

push-server.php

```
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$loop   = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$pusher = new MyApp\Pusher;

// Listen for the web server to make a ZeroMQ push after an ajax request
$context = new React\ZMQ\Context($loop);
$pull = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
$pull->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555'); // Binding to 127.0.0.1 means the only client that can connect is itself
$pull->on('message', array($pusher, 'onBlogEntry'));

// Set up our WebSocket server for clients wanting real-time updates
$webSock = new React\Socket\Server($loop);
$webSock->listen(8080, '0.0.0.0'); // Binding to 0.0.0.0 means remotes can connect
$webServer = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
    new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
        new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
            new Ratchet\Wamp\WampServer(
                $pusher
            )
        )
    ),
    $webSock
);

$loop->run();
```

Pusher.php

```
namespace MyApp;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use Ratchet\Wamp\WampServerInterface;

class Pusher implements WampServerInterface {

protected $subscribedTopics = array();

public function onSubscribe(ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic) {
    $this->subscribedTopics[$topic->getId()] = $topic;
}

/**
 * @param string JSON'ified string we'll receive from ZeroMQ
 */
public function onBlogEntry($entry) {
    $entryData = json_decode($entry, true);

    // If the lookup topic object isn't set there is no one to publish to
    if (!array_key_exists($entryData['category'], $this->subscribedTopics)) {
        return;
    }

    $topic = $this->subscribedTopics[$entryData['category']];

    // re-send the data to all the clients subscribed to that category
    $topic->broadcast($entryData);
}
public function onUnSubscribe(ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic) {
}
public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
}
public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
}
public function onCall(ConnectionInterface $conn, $id, $topic, array $params) {
    // In this application if clients send data it's because the user hacked around in console
    $conn->callError($id, $topic, 'You are not allowed to make calls')->close();
}
public function onPublish(ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic, $event, array $exclude, array $eligible) {
    // In this application if clients send data it's because the user hacked around in console
    $conn->close();
}
public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
}
}
```

index.php

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Главная страница</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Заголовок</h1>

<script src="https://autobahn.s3.amazonaws.com/js/autobahn.min.js"></script>
<script>
var conn = new ab.Session('ws://localhost:8080',
    function() {
        conn.subscribe('kittensCategory', function(topic, data) {
            // This is where you would add the new article to the DOM (beyond the scope of this tutorial)
            console.log('New article published to category "' + topic + '" : ' + data.title);
        });
    },
    function() {
        console.warn('WebSocket connection closed');
    },
    {'skipSubprotocolCheck': true}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась после того как я выключил антивирус Касперского. Интересно, почему?